# PostgreSQL trigger have the same OLD/NEW values when explicitly update a column

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with a `boolean` column and an UPDATE trigger. When I try to explicitly update the column value from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, the values in the column are correct, i.e. OLD being `FALSE` and NEW being `TRUE`. When I try to change from `TRUE` to `FALSE`, both OLD and NEW will be `FALSE`. I am using NOTIFY to check these values inside trigger.

Has anyone experienced this weird behavior?

Below are some of the trigger function, the business logic I thought irrelevant are omitted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locker_before_state_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
DECLARE 
    l_reservation_id INT;
BEGIN
    -- for debugging
    PERFORM pg_notify('locker_is_alive_update', 'N' || NEW);
    PERFORM pg_notify('locker_is_alive_update', 'O' || OLD);

    -- this check will fail when update from TRUE to FALSE
    IF (NEW.state = OLD.state) AND (OLD.is_alive <> NEW.is_alive) THEN
        PERFORM pg_notify('locker_is_alive_update', NEW.id || ',' || NEW.is_alive);
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    ...

RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER locker_before_state_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON locker FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE locker_before_state_update();
```

Comment: The conditions in your `if` statement would fail if any of the columns is `null`. Could that be the case?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope, all the column values are not null.

Answer (score 1):

You should experience weird behaviour because you are returning `NULL` inside your if-statement. Actually what happens is that the update doesn't get done at all. I tested it by replacing `RETURN NULL` with `RETURN NEW` and it worked as expected. The if-part:

```
IF (NEW.state = OLD.state) AND (OLD.is_alive <> NEW.is_alive) THEN
    PERFORM pg_notify('locker_is_alive_update', NEW.id || ',' || NEW.is_alive || ',' || OLD.is_alive);
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```